# How to remove invalid characters from a hyphenated serial key while preserving the single hyphen separator rule?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove letters from `(a1-800-b-400)`, but naively doing so results in `(1-800--400)`.

How do I get `(1-800-400)`?

If it involves `RegExp`, please explain how it works.

Comment: Yes, the solution is a regex. It's really simple, why don't you try to write it yourself? Hint: `[^...]` matches any characters that aren't in `...`

Comment: hold on, you said any character not numeric, bracket or hyphen, then your example removes a hyphen!

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `(1-800--400)`? Do you also want to collapse multiple hyphens into a single hyphen after removing other characters?

Comment: That's also a simple regular expression.

Comment: "(a1-800-b-400)".replace(/[^   \-(   0-9)]/g,'').replace(/\-\-+/g,'-')==="(1-800-400)"

Answer (score 0):

This is the `RegExp` you need:

## `/[^\d\()-]/g`

`/` `/` are simply indicators that you're writing a `RegExp` literal.

The trailing `g` flag means find all matches, instead of just one.

Everything between the `[` `]` are the characters you want to match.

But the `^` symbol means the opposite; **don't** match.

`\d` means `Number`, `\(` means open parenthesis (escaped), `)` is obvious, as is `-`.

```js
const regExpA = /[^\d\()-]/g;
const regExpB = /--/g;
const string = '(a1-800-b-400)';
const result = string
  .replace(regExpA, '')   // (1-800--400)
  .replace(regExpB, '-'); // (1-800-400)

console.log(result);
```